# Is this equivariant function constant?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, lattices, group-actions

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group (think of $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$), $B$ its Borel (standard minimal parabolic) subgroup (think of upper triangular subgroup), and let $\Gamma \leq G$ be a cocompact lattice in $G$ (think $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$). Let $V$ be some unitary representation of $\Gamma$.

Let $f:G/B \times G \to V$ be a function (*I am unsure if we need continuity or measurability*) that has equivariance under certain actions of $G$ and $\Gamma$ as follows:

1. For any $g \in G$,
   $$f(gxB, y)=f(xB,yg)$$
   for $xB \in G/B$ and $y \in G$. That is, $g$ multiplication on the left on cosets flips to right multiplication on the second coordinate.
2. For any $\gamma \in \Gamma$,
   $$f(xB, \gamma y) = \gamma f(xB,y)$$
   Here $\gamma$ multiplication on the left on the second coordinate pops out to act on $f(xB,y) \in V$ via the representation.

My question:

> Do these equivariance conditions force $f$ to be a constant function? Or at least, can we reduce $f(xP,y)=F(y)$ for some $F:G/\Gamma \to V$? That is, can it be reduced to a function just on the second coordinate (the first coordinate being irrelevant)?

The $G$-equivariance severly limits the values the function can take, for instance,
$$f(xB,y)=f(B,yx)=f(yxB,1)$$
So it is sufficient to know the function on $f(B,y)$ for $y \in G$. In fact, it is sufficient to know it on just representatives of cosets $G/B$ since if $y=ab$ for $b \in B$, then we can use $G$-equivariance again. In fact, we can use representatives of double cosets $\Gamma a B$ to completely know what the function values are for the entire domain.

However, can more be said based on the interplay of the two equivariance conditions, maybe due to $B$ being Borel and $\Gamma$ being a cocompact discrete subgroup? I am looking into certain ergodicity results on action of $G$ on the flag variety $G/B$, etc. but am curious if this can be understood without the heavy machinery.

NOTE: There exists a way to show that such an $f$ is indeed essentially constant by assuming some additional structure. We can reinterpret the $\Gamma$-equivariance condition to express $f$ as a function
$$\tilde{f}: G/B \to \left( G/\Gamma \to V\right)$$
and the $G$-equivariance condition now involves an action of $G$ on functions from $G/\Gamma \to V$. If we insist that
$$\tilde{f}:G/B \to L^2(G/\Gamma,V)$$
then $L^2(G/\Gamma,V)$ is an induced representation of $V$ from $\Gamma$ to $G$, on which $G$ acts *norm-continuously*. This continuity can be exploited (using Howe-Moore theorem about fixed points of unitary representations) to show that $\tilde{f}$ is essentially constant. In fact, this method can be used to show even that $G$-equivariant $\tilde{f}:G/B \times G/B \to L^2(G/\Gamma,V)$ is essentially constant.
There is also another way of doing this for $\tilde{f}:G/B \to L^2(G/\Gamma,V)$ using ergodicty of the $G$-action on $G/B \times G/B$. This is done by introducing a $G$-invariant function $f':G/B \times G/B \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f'(xB,yB)=<f(xB), f(yB) >$, which would be forced to be essentially constant.  But this method doesn't work for $\tilde{f}:G/B \times G/B \to L^2(G/\Gamma,V)$ (since that would need ergodicity of the $G$-action on $G/B \times G/B \times G/B \times G/B$ which we know to be false).

What I'm hoping for is a proof that doesn't involve this additional structure (especially continuity of the group action), and one that could go through also for the case of functions $f:G/B \times G/B \times G \to V$.

Comment: Fix $x$ and let $y$ vary. If $f$ is continuous and $\Gamma$ acts trivially on $V$, the answer is yes, as $\Gamma B$ is dense in $G$.